# The offset option of xdvipdfmx does not work?

Tags: xetex, xdvipdfmx

`xdvipdfmx -help` shows two options named `-x` and `-y`:

```
-x dimension  Set horizontal offset [1.0in]
-y dimension  Set vertical offset [1.0in]
```

However if I create a file

```
\font\f=cmr10
\f a
\end
```

Then execute

```
xetex -ini -no-pdf 1.tex
xdvipdfmx -x 0 -y 0 -o a.pdf 1
xdvipdfmx -o b.pdf 1
```

The two files produced look exactly the same. What is the actual effect of these two options?

Comment: Apparently `xdvipdfmx` inherits the options from `dvipdfmx` (via `dvipdfm`), but actually doesn't use them. As to why, I guess one has to ask the developers.